# Run Fiji from command line?

Tags: command-line, macros, imagej

- *Here is what I want to do:*

I want to run [Fiji](http://fiji.sc/Fiji) from command-line, to do something like batch image processing. I imagine by typing some command at some console, some batch file can be launched to execute some macro. In this case, the [Fiji](http://fiji.sc/Fiji) GUI will not show up, but the processing will be running behind the scene.

- *Here is what I have done:*

I simply tried the [FIji headless](http://fiji.sc/wiki/index.php/Headless) , but when I tried `./Build.sh misc/headless.jar` as the web suggested, the console prompt returns **could not find project for artifactID 'headless';** 
I also tried [Javassist](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/),pretty much just built it, but have not figure out how to use it.

- *Here is the problem I am encountering:*

When I type `fiji --headless HelloWorldMacro.ijm`, nothing happened, where inside the HelloWorldMacro.ijm is `printf("Hello world!");`

I am wondering, how should I run [FIji](http://fiji.sc/Fiji) from command line? Is what I have tried on the right track? If so, what additional work/changes needed to make it work? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't understand why someone is voting this question down? For what reasons could you please tell me here whoever did this? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the record:

Johannes Schindelin [answered](http://imagej.1557.x6.nabble.com/headless-not-working-tp5006126p5006137.html) this question on the ImageJ mailing list (additionally pointing out why the [ImageJ mailing list](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/list.html) is the most suitable place for this kind of discussions).

In short, either of the following should work:

```
fiji --headless --console HelloWorldMacro.ijm
```

or

```
fiji --headless HelloWorldMacro.ijm > output.txt
cat output.txt
```